# How to render binary data on canvas using WebGl?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, webgl, binary-data

I am using PNaCl ffmpeg to open, read and decode RTSP stream. I am now having raw video frames which I need to transfer to WebGl to render on the canvas.

How can I render binary data on the canvas?

I am running the following code: I presume that I should get a grey canvas after running this code, because I am passing RGBA values of (120,120,120,1) to the synthetic data.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

var gl = initWebGL(canvas); //function initializes webgl

initViewport(gl, canvas); //initializes view port

console.log('viewport initialized');

var data = [];
for (var i = 0 ; i < 256; i++){
  data.push(120,120,120,1.0);
}

console.log(data);

var pixels = new Uint8Array(data); // 16x16 RGBA image
var texture = gl.createTexture();

gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
gl.texImage2D(
  gl.TEXTURE_2D, // target
  0, // mip level
  gl.RGBA, // internal format
  16, 16, // width and height
  0, // border
  gl.RGBA, //format
  gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, // type
  pixels // texture data
);

console.log('pixels');
console.log(pixels);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

I should get a grey 16x16 box being represented on the canvas, but I am not getting that. What additional steps do I need to take to correctly render the 2D bitmap on the canvas?

PS. I am taking help from [this article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webgl/typed_arrays/).

[Console output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTV5W.png)

Comment: probably of some help : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Tutorial/Animating_textures_in_WebGL

Comment: Thanks for that, but since I am using an RTSP stream, it is cannot be played in a video tag, I am using PNaCl ffmpeg to get the stream, so getting the data from the video element will not work.

Comment: You shouldnt be doing "gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, pixels);" for the texture data. The texture data is passed via teximage2d. Also post the full code, and the Console output from the browser.

Comment: @prabindh Yes I have removed the gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, pixels), the output remains the same. I have posted the full javascript code in the edit (except initWebGL which initializes WegGl and initviewport for viewport). I have also added the console output as an image in the end

Comment: You are passing a alpha value of 1.0 but the buffer is unsigned 8 bit. The Alpha will be rounded to 1, and yo will need some good eyes to see that. Alpha is a 8 bit value from 0 - 255 you will have to set it higher than one to see anything.

Comment: Yes I have changed the alpha value to 255 (i.e. full opacity), but still no result.

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out in the comments, alpha in WebGL in the type of texture you're creating is 0 to 255. You're putting in 1.0 which = 1/255 or an alpha of 0.004

But on top of that you say

> I am running the following code: I presume that I should get a grey canvas after running this code

That code is not enough for WebGL. [WebGL requires you to supply a vertex shader and fragment shader](http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-how-it-works.html), vertex data for vertices and then call either `gl.drawArrays` or `gl.drawElements` to render something. The code you provided doesn't do those things and without those things we can't tell what else you're doing.

You're also only supplying mip level 0. You either need to supply mips or set texture filtering so only the first level is used otherwise the texture is unrenderable (you'll get a warning about it in the JavaScript console of most browsers).

Here's a working example

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");

var data = [];
for (var i = 0 ; i < 256; i++){
  data.push(120,120,120,255);
}

var pixels = new Uint8Array(data); // 16x16 RGBA image
var texture = gl.createTexture();

gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
gl.texImage2D(
  gl.TEXTURE_2D, // target
  0, // mip level
  gl.RGBA, // internal format
  16, 16, // width and height
  0, // border
  gl.RGBA, //format
  gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, // type
  pixels // texture data
);
gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);  // you need to do this or set filtering

// compiles and links the shaders and looks up uniform and attribute locations
var programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, ["vs", "fs"]);
var arrays = {
  position: [
     -1, -1, 0, 
      1, -1, 0, 
     -1,  1, 0, 
     -1,  1, 0, 
      1, -1, 0, 
      1,  1, 0,
  ],
};
// calls gl.createBuffer, gl.bindBuffer, gl.bufferData for each array
var bufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, arrays);

var uniforms = {
  u_texture: texture,
};

gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
// calls gl.bindBuffer, gl.enableVertexAttribArray, gl.vertexAttribPointer
twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);
// calls gl.activeTexture, gl.bindTexture, gl.uniformXXX
twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, uniforms);
// calls gl.drawArrays or gl.drawElements
twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, gl.TRIANGLES, bufferInfo);
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<script id="vs" type="notjs">
attribute vec4 position;

varying vec2 v_texcoord;

void main() {
  gl_Position = position;

  // Since we know we'll be passing in -1 to +1 for position
  v_texcoord = position.xy * 0.5 + 0.5;
}
  </script>
  <script id="fs" type="notjs">
precision mediump float;

uniform sampler2D u_texture;

varying vec2 v_texcoord;

void main() {
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texcoord);
}
  </script>
  <script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/twgl.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```